# ElementUI - in el-select &nbsp can't translate into space

Tags: jquery, vue.js, element

when i use el-select, my label has &nbsp, but when display in browser it can't change into space

This is running element-ui@2.10

```html
        <el-select v-model="value" filterable @change="currentSel" id="demoSelect" class="el_select_width">
            <el-option
              v-for="item in job_info"
              :key="item.value"
              :label="item.label"
              :value="item.value">
            </el-option>
        </el-select>
```

The value of the label is ”my&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;label&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1“

I expect the output is "my   label   1"

But the actual output is "my label 1"

Comment: Why do not just add more spaces on your model definition?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little unclear what you're asking, especially as it isn't clear whether SO is misrepresenting your question by interpreting some of your escape sequences as HTML. I've done some experimenting with `el-select` to try to deduce what you're probably asking.

If possible I suggest using JavaScript string escaping rather than an HTML entity. For a non-breaking space that would be `\u00a0`.

e.g.

```js
"my\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0\u00a0label\u00a0\u00a0\u00a01"
```

Keep in mind that `&nbsp;` is not some magical incantation to make the browser insert a non-breaking space, it's just a named entity used to refer to a Unicode character. That same character can be included directly in a string, as in my example, dodging any assumptions about downstream escaping.

An alternative might be to use normal spaces and some `white-space` CSS, but that still requires you to remove the `&nbsp;` from the label.

Comment: thanks! change &nbsp; into \u00a0 then it's working!